# How to merge pandas dataframes and overwrite the values corresponding to the matching rows in one of them?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I would like to merge two dataframes in python as shown below.

If df1 is : [image]

and df2: [image]

I would like the outcome to look like this: 
[image]

In essence, I need the two dataframes to merge in terms of days and the days to be in order; the days have corresponding rate values which need to remain the same unless for example if you look at day 9 it is in both dfs and the rates differ the rate from df2 needs to be retained.

I am really knew to python and I do not understand well the pd.merge so I would be extremely grateful is someone could help.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `combine_first`

```
df2.set_index('day',inplace=True)
df2=df2.combine_first(df1.set_index('day')).reset_index()
df2
Out[552]: 
   day  val
0    2  1.0
1    3  1.0
2    4  2.0
3    5  2.0
4    6  2.0
5    7  2.0
6    8  2.0
7    9  3.0
8   12  3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), [sort_values()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
>> outcome = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values('days').drop_duplicates(subset=['days'],keep='last').reset_index(drop=True)
>> outcome
    days    interest rate
0   2   0.02560
1   3   0.01230
2   4   0.01470
3   5   0.25600
4   6   0.78560
5   7   0.09850
6   8   0.05890
7   9   0.02268
8   12  0.01235
```

Comment: Two 9 in days .